# Is it required to set up a custom domain on Mailgun?

Tags: mailgun

As stated in the title, is it required to set up a custom domain on Mailgun? or ok to continue using the "sandbox" domain name?

If optional, what is the downside of using the "sandbox" domain?

Answer (score 2):

It is OK to continue to use the sandbox domain, it will just not have a recognizable domain

Answer (score 1):

Sandboxed domains are quite limited in that you can only send emails to authorized recipients which need to be configured inside the UI manually.

Beyond that, even if you only have a small set of users then you need to also set up SPF and DKIM for best practices (Yahoo will reject all emails without this and DMARC) which means having a domain name anyway.

So for the hassle, you are better off just configuring your own domain and working from there.